# How to create a window that displays text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window, tk-toolkit

I want to make a password generator that generates a random password using tkinter imports that makes a window showing the password in a big bold font. I have the generator done and I know how to make a window with tkinter but I'm not sure how to put them together since I'm still learning haha.

Comment: You should be able to get an answer to this by working through a very basic tkinter tutorial. It's not clear why you need help beyond a tutorial.

Comment: Sorry @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get a large bold text window.

```
from tkinter import *


password = ("Hello")
root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set(password)

l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.config(font=("bold", 50))
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To set the text to the password, use your generator code and set the password output to a variable named "password". Also i have added the line "password = ("Hello")" to demonstrate the code. You should delete this when you add it to your generator.